# Why am I getting different values for len(bins) and numb_bins when using matplotlib histogram module?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I've generated a histogram using data from a file. Yet when I print the len(bins) it is different to the number of bins?

```
with open ('EHSS.dat') as f:
        data = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

x = [ float(i) for i in data]

num_bins = 7

plt.figure(0)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, facecolor='purple', alpha=0.5)
plt.savefig('fig0.png')

print(len(bins), num_bins)
```

This code gives len(bins) = 8 while num_bins = 7, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the [wiki](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)

> **bins** : *array*
>
> > The edges of the bins. **Length nbins + 1** (nbins left edges and right edge of last bin). Always a single array even when multiple data sets are passed in.